# Maven scala archetypes comparison

Tags: scala, maven, comparison, archetypes

When I create a scala project in Netbeans I normally use the maven-archetype-scala-executable, but I see there are a lot more archetypes to choose from, made by different authors.

How do all these archetypes compare? What are their benefits and restrictions?

Those listed for me are:

```
bugvm-scala-template
camel-archetype-scala
cdap-spark-scala-archetype
flink-quickstart-scala
iobeam-spark-scala-maven-archetype
liftweb-archetype-blank (org.scala-tools.archetypes)
maven-archetype-scala-executable (com.github.igor-petruk.archetypes)
quickstart-scala (eu.stratosphere)
scala-archetype-simple (net.alchim31.maven)
scala-archetype-simple (org.scala-tools.archetypes)
scala-quickstart-archetype (pl.org.miki)
wicket-scala-archetype
wicketstuff-scala-archetype
```

Comment: This is really too broad to answer. One cannot compare every archetype there is.

Comment: Simplified answer is that archetype just creates directory (package) structure, pom.xml with standard dependencies + some standard class files or config files related to particular project. As you can see some of the archetypes on the list are specific to the framework such as `iobeam-spark-scala` is archetype created by `iobeam` platform project to give you head start for development with their platform providing all mentioned above (directory structure, dependencies etc...). Similarly for other archetypes

Comment: @MichaelDD If you could provide this as an answer, I can set that as the accepted answer.